# Creating a div element inside nth child in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Currently, I'm working on building a dynamic form in angular 4 and I have stummbled upon an issue where I will have to drag and drop the fields into the form area.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row col-12">
<div class="col-5">
    <div class=" card row col-12">
        <div class="card-header">
            Basic Fields
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6" draggable="true" appDraggable [dragData]="{ data : 'shortAnswer' }" (onDragStart)="onDragStart($event)">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrows icon-drag fa-lg"></i>
                    <a>Short Answer</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" draggable="true" appDraggable [dragData]="{ data : 'longAnswer' }" (onDragStart)="onDragStart($event)">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrows icon-drag fa-lg"></i>
                    <a>Long Answer</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6" draggable="true" appDraggable [dragData]="{ data : 'section' }" (onDragStart)="onDragStart($event)">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrows icon-drag fa-lg"></i>
                    <a>Section</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col-7">
    <div appDropTarget id="myForm" style="width: 100%; height: 600pc; border: 1px solid black;" (onDrop)="onDrop($event)" >
        fdffgdg
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a custom directive called `appDraggable` which will help me in dragging the component and which works fine.
And I have another custom directive called `appDropTarget` which will help me in rendering the component and which is being dropped in the area.

`onDrop($event)` will be called whenever there is a field that is being dropped in the `appDropTarget`. And there is a drop service which will help me get the data that is being inputted.

> **TS**

```
onDrop(event) {
  console.log(document.getElementById('myForm').children);
  if (event.data === 'section') {
    let r = document.createElement('div');
    r.setAttribute('id', 'sectionId');
    r.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-12 section');
    r.setAttribute('appDropTarget' , '');
    r.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    r.setAttribute('appDraggable','');
    r.setAttribute('style', ` background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px; `);
    document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(r);
  }else {
    let r = document.createElement('span');
    let y = document.createElement('INPUT');
    y.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    y.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
    r.setAttribute('draggable','true');
    r.setAttribute('appDraggable','');
    y.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Contact');
    y.setAttribute('Name', 'textelement_' + 2);
    r.appendChild(y);
    r.setAttribute('id', 'id_' + 2);
document.getElementById('myForm').setAttributeNode(this.dragService.dropId)
.appendChild(r); // THIS IS WHERE IM FACING ISSUE
          }
        }
```

So, as I have mentioned I need to render a form fields inside a div and I should be able to append the child inside the section which I have created dynamically

how can I render the form elements into the section?

**EDIT**

so, my HTML should look something like this

```
     <div>
     <!-- /// MAIN FORM DIV  -->
    <div id="sectionId" class="col-md-12 section" appdroptarget="" draggable="true" appdraggable="" style=" background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px; ">
<!-- /// OTHER FORM ELEMENTS SHOULD RENDER -->
</div>
<!-- CAN HAVE MORE SECTIONS AND SECTION CONTAINS MORE FIELDS -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "angular way" would be to use data binding:

1. Create the structure of your form as a model
2. Bind view to your form model
3. Update model on drop

There are not enough information in your question to create a complete example, but the following should show the concept:

Section

```
export interface Section {
  name: string;
  questions: Question[];
}
```

FormContainerComponent

```
export class FormContainerComponent {
  questionnaire: Section[] = [];
}
```

form-container.template.html

```
<form>
  <div *ngFor="let section of questionnaire" class="section">
    <div *ngFor="let question of section;">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Now just listen for drops and add the elements to your questionnaire. View will update automatically.

in FormContainerComponent add

```
@HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
handleContainerDrop(event) {
  // your logic to create "theDroppedSection"
  this.questionnaire.push(theDroppedSection);
}
```

### Using different components for controls

Assuming you don't want to have always one single html input element as form control, you can create one angular component for each "control type" and create something like a FormControlContainer that is responsible for loading the right type.

To stay in the questionnaire example: Create on "QuestionComponent" that can load different question types, e.g. "YesNoQuestionComponent", "SingleTextInputQuestionComponent", …

This is explained in https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader - just replace their "AdBannerComponent" with "QuestionComponent" and see the question types as "AdItem"s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, initially this is the way I started with but now I need to work it in a different way. I'm trying to make something like this https://www.formstack.com/admin/form/embedded_builder

Comment: That should work quite well. I'm doing it with a similar data structure. What was the problem?

Comment: so, if I'm able to drag those field elements then can I change the model value?

Comment: On drag start, you add data to your drag event, that lets you identify what was dragged. Based on this data, you know how to update your model in drop handler. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API